# Using getThirdPartySetting() to get node type configurations in other hooks

Tags: hooks, 8, nodes

In a Drupal 8 instance, [getThirdPartySetting()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Config%21Entity%21ThirdPartySettingsInterface.php/function/ThirdPartySettingsInterface%3A%3AgetThirdPartySetting/8.5.x) function to save node type configurations using the `NodeTypeInterface` object like below

```
  $type = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  $fields = $type->getThirdPartySetting('field_config', 'type_fields', array(''));
```

Now I need to use the configurations in a hook for validation, to be particular in `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter()`

```
function hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(&$fields
  , \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle)
```

It contains objects of `EntityTypeInterface` but not that of `NodeTypeInterface`. Now how can I access the configuration of the particular node type in the hook?

When I tried something like this in `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter`:

```
  $node_type = \Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType::load($bundle);
  $selected_fields = $node_type->getThirdPartySetting('field_config',
    'field_scope', '');
```

It throws an error as : *Call to a member function getThirdPartySetting() on a non-object*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$bundle is the node type (ID), so you can load the node type based on that.

```
$node_type = \Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType::load($bundle);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. But how can I get an object of `NodeTypeInterface` class. It contains the function `getThirdPartySetting`.

Comment: Exactly like I said? $node_type is the loaded node type entity. You have getThirdPartySettings() on there.

Comment: I updated my question please check it. It throws me an error if used getThirdPartySettings(). I  can't even print to see how the object looks inside the hook. :(

Comment: I guess that means that you are missing a check if the entity type actually is node. It could also be something else like user or so.

Comment: That's a good catch berdir. I also confused how to pass the `$options` argument in `addConstraint()` in `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter`. I will start a new post on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is scenario in Drupal 8, retrieve the third party settings of "field_image" inside the preprocess function. below code used to getThirdPartySettings values.

```
$node_type = \Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'bundlename');
$settings = $node_type['field_image']->getThirdPartySetting('mymodule', 'field_scope');
```

It is working fine. :)